# Скрыть панель задач при полноэкранном режиме формы. WinForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, framework

Пытаюсь реализовать в моей форме полноэкранный режим (как в играх), но не получается перекрыть панель задач. Можете объяснить, как это делается?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WorldMap
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AutoSize = true;
            
        }

        public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MouseEventArgs rato = e as MouseEventArgs;
            Bitmap b = ((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
            int x = rato.X * b.Width / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width;
            int y = rato.Y * b.Height / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height;
            Color c = b.GetPixel(x, y);
            textBox1.Text = c.ToString();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.F11);
            {
                this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
                
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized`

Comment: Maximized включено в свойствах формы

Comment: Погуглить например, первая ссыль [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022789/hide-taskbar-in-winforms-application) я когда то подобное решение через win api использовал

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100412-00/?p=14353

Answer (score 1):

```
Form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
Form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```